# C# help with Extension Method - Converting collection to another type

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, type-conversion

I want to convert from

```
 public class Party
 {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set;}
 }
```

and convert to

```
 public class Contact
 {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set;}
        public string Company {get;set;}
        public string Source {get;set;}    
 }
```

I tried using this extension method

```
   public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TTo> ConvertTo<TTo, TFrom>(this IEnumerable<TFrom> fromList)
        {
            return ConvertTo<TTo, TFrom>(fromList, TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TFrom)));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TTo> ConvertTo<TTo, TFrom>(this IEnumerable<TFrom> fromList, TypeConverter converter)
        {
            return fromList.Select(t => (TTo)converter.ConvertTo(t, typeof(TTo)));
        }
}
```

**I get this error TypeConverter is unable to convert 'Party' to 'Contact'**

```
    var parties = new List<Party>();
        parties.Add(new Party { Name = "name 1", Status = "status 1" });
        parties.Add(new Party { Name = "name 2", Status = "status 2" });

        var results = parties.ConvertTo<Contact, Party>().ToList();
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct conversion between the type Party and the Type contact (polymorphic or inheritance based).

You need to implement a TypeConverter for your types so that .NET knows how to convert between those two types:

[MSDN - TypeConverter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx)

[MSDN - How to Implement a TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx)

Once you create your TypeConverters, you have to decorate your two classes with the TypeConverterAttribute so that the Framework can get an instance of your TypeConverter at Runtime:

```
public class PartyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    // Implementation
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(PartyTypeConverter)]
public class Party
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

You could also attempt to mimic the (what I'm guessing) is the desired behavior using LINQ (even though you'll lose the generic abilities):

```
var contacts = parties.Select(p => new Contact {
    Type = p.Type,
    Name = p.Name,
    Status = p.Status
});
```

Comment: yes the LINQ approach will work.  Thought there might be another way of doing this.

Comment: Unfortunately not. You either have to implement the TypeConverter approach or use LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

here is a slightly different way, though at its core it still about simply copying member values from one object to another

add this to your Contact class

```
public static explicit operator Contact(Party p)
{
    return new Contact
    {
        Type = p.Type,
        Name = p.Name,
        Status = p.Status
    };
}
```

then convert like this:

```
List<Party> parties = new List<Party>();
parties.Add(new Party { Name = "Foo", Status = "Bar" });

parties.Select<Party, Contact>(p => (Contact)p)
```

you may want to enclose last bit into some extension method, but I don't see a point...